# Recommended method to import a .csv file into Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What is your recommended way to import .csv files into Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2?

I'd like something fast, as I have a directory with a lot of .csv files (>500MB spread across 500 .csv files).

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 on Win 7 x64.

**Update: Solution**

Here's how I solved the problem the end:

1. I abandoned trying to use LINQ to Entities to do the job. It works - but it doesn't support bulk insert, so its about 20x slower. Maybe the next version of LINQ to Entities will support this.
2. Took the advice given on this thread, used bulk insert.
3. I created a T-SQL stored procedure that uses bulk insert. Data goes into a staging table, is normalized then copied into the target tables.
4. I mapped the stored procedure into C# using the LINQ to Entities framework (there is a video on www.learnvisualstudio.net showing how to do this).
5. I wrote all the code to cycle through files, etc in C#.
6. This method eliminates the biggest bottleneck, which is reading tons of data off the drive and inserting it into the database.

The reason why this method is extremely quick at reading .csv files? Microsoft SQL Server gets to import the files directly from the hard drive straight into the database, using its own highly optimized routines. Most of the other C# based solutions require much more code, and some (like LINQ to Entities) end up having to pipe the data slowly into the database via the C#-to-SQL-server link.

Yes, I know it'd be nicer to have 100% pure C# code to do the job, but in the end:

- (a) For this particular problem, using T-SQL requires *much* less code compared to C#, about 1/10th, especially for the logic to denormalize the data from the staging table. This is simpler and more maintainable.
- (b) Using T-SQL means you can take advantage of the native bulk insert procedures, which speeds things up from 20-minute wait to a 30-second pause.

Comment: Nice one (and p l u s  o n e)! Thanks for the tip - useful for me too. Just wondering why it would be nice to have a 100% C# code to do the job? For me it was nice to have a 100% T-SQL solution without any C# code at all :) I used xp_dirtree to get the list of my CSV files. See http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdirtree-to-list-all-files.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using BULK INSERT in a T-SQL script seems to be a good solution.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

You can get the list of files in your directory with xp_cmdshell and the dir command (with a bit of cleanup). In the past, I tried to do something like this with sp_OAMethod and VBScript functions and had to use the dir method because I had trouble getting the list of files with the FSO object.

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2008/list-files-in-directory/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work nicely. I've updated the question with exactly how the solution worked in the end.

Comment: Ok, I am planning to do the same thing and this is very helpful. However since the stored procedure can be execute multiple times in parallel, I do require bulk insert to be done to a random staging table(meaning a unique table name everytime), I will do cleanup of the staging table once processing is done.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do anything with the data in the files other than insert it, then I would recommend using SSIS. It can not only insert and/or update, it can also clean the data for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info on SSIS, it looks interesting. I had to install Visual Studio 2008 to check it out (its not available in Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: SSIS is crap, don't use SSIS. Why? No unit testing, sometimes ending up with duplicate business logic between the app and the SSIS package, etc al. Only use SSIS if your import process is simple, you have no need of unit testsing, and no part of it uses any logic similiar to the rest of your app.

Answer (score 2):

First officially supported way of importing large text files is with command line tool called "bcp" (Bulk Copy Utility), very useful for huge amounts of binary data.

Please check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

However, in SQL Server 2008 I presume that BULK INSERT command would be your choice number one, because on the first place it became a part of standard command set. If for any reason you have to maintain vertical compatibility, I'd stick to bcp utility, available for SQL Server 2000 too.

HTH :)

EDITED LATER: Googling around I recalled that SQL Server 2000 had BULK INSERT command too... however, there was obviously some reason I sticked up to bcp.exe, and I cannot recall why... perhaps of some limits, I guess.

Comment: BCP will work fine, however, I've decided to go with bulk insert as I can easily map the stored procedure into C# using the LINQ to Entity framework. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

I should recommend this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

namespace ReadDataFromCSVFile
  {
    static class Program
      {
        static void Main()
        {
            string csv_file_path=@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv";
            DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);
            Console.WriteLine("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
        {
            DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
            try
            {
              using(TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
                 {
                    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string column in colFields)
                    {
                        DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                        datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                    }
                    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                        //Making empty value as null
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (fieldData[i] == "")
                            {
                                fieldData[i] = null;
                            }
                        }
                        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return csvData;
        }
      }
    }

//Copy the DataTable to SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy

    function static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable csvData)
    {
       using(SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ProductHost;Initial Catalog=yourDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
            {
              dbConnection.Open();
              using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
                {
                    s.DestinationTableName = "Your table name";

                    foreach (var column in csvFileData.Columns)
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());

                    s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
                 }
             }
      }
```

Comment: Kindly provide a short description. So, we could understand what is what and why you use it. It will very helpful for beginners like me

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of all your CSVs are the same i recomend you to use Integration Services (SSIS) in order to loop between them and insert all of them into the same table.

Comment: Thanks for the info on SSIS, it looks interesting and extremely powerful. I had to install Visual Studio 2008 to check it out (its not available in Visual Studio 2010).

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is not exactly your question.  But, if you get into a situation where you use a straight insert use tablock and insert multiple rows.  Depends on the row size but I usually go for 600-800 rows at at time.  If it is a load into an empty table then sometimes dropping the indexes and creating them after it is loaded is faster.  If you can sort the data on the clustered index before it is loaded.  Use IGNORE_CONSTRAINTS and IGNORE_TRIGGERS if you can.  Put the database in single user mode if you can.

USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
INSERT INTO Production.UnitMeasure with (tablock) 
VALUES (N'FT2', N'Square Feet ', '20080923'), (N'Y', N'Yards', '20080923'), (N'Y3', N'Cubic Yards', '20080923');
GO

Comment: Nice. I'd suggest using this method to insert into the #temp table, then merge the #temp with the main table. Its much faster that way, for some reason.

Comment: Possibly the main table is active so getting holdlock is difficult.  What is nice about #temp tables is you have exclusive access.  Table to table seems to get a higher priority than an external connection. I can tell you from experience that loading sorted by the clustered index is major.  If I cannot sort the source I will load it into a #temp so I can load into the real table sorted by cluster index.  But we are not supposed to use stackoverflow as a discussion thread.